# Logstash A plugin had an unrecoverable error

Tags: java, logstash, kibana, devops, elk

I have installed ELK using docker from following link https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk/tree/release-7.x

It works very well before, but recenty I got an issue on several new servers. The issue related with Logstash I installed on the some new servers it no longer send logs to the ELK server (2 earlier servers work very well). All the new servers are running on the AWS ARM64 processor with Ubuntu 20.04 OS.

Here is my Logstash conf

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-17-36:~$ cat /etc/logstash/conf.d/logstash.conf                
input {                                                                         
  stdin {}                                                                      
  file {                                                                        
    path => "/home/ubuntu/logs/*.log"                                           
    codec => "line"                                                             
    type => "logback"                                                           
  }                                                                             
}                                                                               
output {                                                                        
  elasticsearch {                                                               
    hosts => ["http://my.domain.here:9200"]                                
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{[@metadata][version]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"      
    user => "elastic"                                                           
    password => "mypasswordhere"                                           
  }                                                                             
                                                                                
  stdout {                                                                      
    codec => rubydebug                                                          
  }                                                                             
}
```

And here is the error:

```
[logstash.log][ERROR] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Pipeline_id:main
  Plugin: <LogStash::Inputs::File path=>["/home/ubuntu/logs/*.log"], codec=><LogStash::Codecs::Line id=>"line_be8567e0-c2ed-4fb5-bb1e-d5547b6e82ca", enable_metric=>true, charset=>"UTF-8", delimiter=>"\n">, id=>"c268f57e10bc6f90059c4e8a0c16df4e1833157f2a8fc58a01a046529bd84b48", type=>"logback", enable_metric=>true, stat_interval=>1.0, discover_interval=>15, sincedb_write_interval=>15.0, start_position=>"end", delimiter=>"\n", close_older=>3600.0, mode=>"tail", file_completed_action=>"delete", sincedb_clean_after=>1209600.0, file_chunk_size=>32768, file_chunk_count=>140737488355327, file_sort_by=>"last_modified", file_sort_direction=>"asc", exit_after_read=>false, check_archive_validity=>false>
  Error: Operation not permitted - No message available
  Exception: Errno::EPERM
  Stack: org/jruby/RubyFile.java:675:in `chown'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.2.2/lib/filewatch/helper.rb:41:in `write_atomically'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.2.2/lib/filewatch/sincedb_collection.rb:232:in `atomic_write'
org/jruby/RubyMethod.java:119:in `call'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.2.2/lib/filewatch/sincedb_collection.rb:216:in `sincedb_write'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.2.2/lib/filewatch/sincedb_collection.rb:188:in `flush_at_interval'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.2.2/lib/filewatch/watch.rb:57:in `subscribe'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.2.2/lib/filewatch/observing_tail.rb:12:in `subscribe'
/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-input-file-4.2.2/lib/logstash/inputs/file.rb:364:in `run'
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:405:in `inputworker'
/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:396:in `block in start_input'
```

Snapshot of errors above
[image]

FYI, The APMs are working very well.

[image]

Could somebody help me how to fix the error?

Any help could be extremely appreciated.

Comment: I have used some different codec but the issue is still the same

Comment: I do not have a solution, but folks hit this on AARM. On Windows, or if the device the sincedb is on is either a block or character device, then the input uses a non-atomic write. Otherwise it uses an atomic write, which does a chown of the file. This gets EPERM unless you are running as root. How a UNIX file system can not be a block device is beyond me.